# Trying to import news using Feeds xPath html parser

Tags: theming, feeds

been trying to make this work for the pass week now, and can't seem to be able to. I'm trying to import news from a site where there are listed news in a part of the site. All my xpath query works when tested in the chrome console and return what they are supposed to. The context query also work as it should be. But, when I try to import and create node, it just say that there is no new node to imported. Oh...and I'm using tidy to correct the source.

Heres is an example: 
URL: http://www.spartan.com/en/community/blog/spartan-news
XPath Parser setting:
Context: //*[@id='inner']/div[3]/div[2]/div/main/aside/content-provider-secondary/div[2]/div/div/a

Title: h3[text()]
guid: @data-post_id
url: @href
body: h3[text()]

that's just a test of course.
The url field is used as the unique field in the node processor mapping.

It doens't give any error...but does not import anything either and I'm confuse. Is there something specific that need to be done when importing html? I have other feeds setup with xpath xml and they work as intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!